# Incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct in_addr’ from type 'unsigned int'

Tags: c, linux, ip-address, ipv4

I am using Linux for compiling. In the `struct ip` (for IPv4), when I tried to give the value as `ip1.ip_dst = 0xffffffff;`, it got the following error:

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct in_addr’ from type 'unsigned int'  ip.ip_dst = 0xffffffff;`

What value should I give to a variable with `struct in_addr` datatype? And how can I solve this error?

Comment: Use `inet_aton` to convert dotted decimal into struct in_addr datatype. Look at the man page of `inet_aton` to get a full list of available functions.

Answer (score 2):

`in_addr` is a struct with a single `unsigned long` member:

```
struct in_addr ip_dest;
ip_dest.s_addr = 0xffffffffL;
```

Comment: Even this is not working. The same kind of error comes up. Here it is:   `error: Incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct in_addr’ from type ‘long int’
`

Comment: This code doesn't assign to an `in_addr`. Please share the **exact** code you tried.

Comment: he is trying to assign to struct in_addr from long int, so apparently his exact code is this: struct in_addr ip; unsigned i; ip = i; simple error of starter.

Answer (score 1):

I think in Linux,

```
typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;

struct in_addr {
    in_addr_t s_addr;
};
```

you may want to cast your value to (uint32_t)

Read more on this: http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet

Comment: Cast which value, when assigning to what? And why cast at all?